# Newly installed LED lights will not turn off by using the switch

Tags: led

Newly installed LED bulbs will not turn off by using the switch.
I have six lights in my kitchen ceiling controlled by a single pole on off switch, no dimmer. Replaced those incandescent bulbs with LED bulbs. The LED bulbs stay on regardless of the switch position. I pulled the wires from the switch and the LED bulbs still stay on. They are full on, not just Dimming. I removed one of the LED bulbs and put back in an incandescent bulb, reconnected the switch and it works fine. As long as I have that 40 W incandescent bulb in place everything works. It will not shut off when I use all LED bulbs. I actually have to turn off the breaker to get the lights off. They stay off until I flip the switch on again and then they will not turn off.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the switch? Suspect something like: motion sensor, timer, illuminated switch, dimmer, etc. - something that is trying to "leak" through the circuit when off. Still odd, but if it is something other than a truly simple switch, that's the explanation.

Comment: sounds like you have  3 way switch and the other one is supplying the power

Comment: @ 69578 I’m sure you are correct. Since the lights will not turn off even with the switch leg open, by removing the wires on the switch. I just can’t figure out where.

Answer (score 2):

### Defective switch.

Or to be more precise, the switch isn't what you think it is.

Replace it with a switch that *is* what you think it is.

Comment: it is all about power of the mind

Comment: how can it be defective switch if it works with incandescent but not with LED

Comment: @ruskes because it's not a switch. It's some sort of actively-powered dingus that is doing stuff besides just being a switch.

Comment: New discovery--actively-powered dingus- electricity Vudu :) I want one of those, provides power without consuming power

Comment: @Ruskes it's leaking current through the incandescent bulb. You've seen this before.